# JQuery Name Selector Query Issue

Tags: jquery

I'm unsure of the syntax, and can't seem to get it to work in the example below. The code as written works.

```
        var nameOf = "2005JanQ1";
        $('div[name=2005JanQ1]').toggle( "slow", function(){
            alert("done");
        });
```

However, I'd like to use:

```
        var nameOf = "2005JanQ1";
        $('div[name=nameOf]').toggle( "slow", function(){
            alert("done");
        });
```

This does not work. And I'm unsure why. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: string concatenation `$('div[name=' + nameOf + ']')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
var nameOf = "2005JanQ1";
$('div[name=' + nameOf + ']').toggle("slow", function () {
    alert("done");
});
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you. Will accept answer when I can.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
var nameOf = "2005JanQ1";
$('div[name='+ nameOf +']').toggle( "slow", function(){
    alert("done");
});
```